# Shopify Liquid tag javascript rendering

Tags: javascript, ruby, shopify, liquid

I have a homemade liquid tag defined like this:

```
class SomeList < Liquid::Block
  def render(context)
    context.stack do
      context['list_items'] = get_back_list_items()
      render_all(@nodelist, context)
    end
  end
end
```

It can then be used in a template like this:

```
{% some_list %}
  {% for item in list_items %}
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p> 
  {% endfor %}
{% endsome_list %}
```

I would like to add a "load more" feature to this tag that could be triggered by a JS call. I don't have the control of what is inside the block in the template.

I have an idea :

- when the tag is rendered, I also output in the dom its `nodelist` in JSON
- then, I add an Ajax call somewhere that will call a controller. In this call I transmit the tag original nodelist
- in my controller I instantiate a context and transmit somehow the nodelist to my tag and re-render it with some new params
- I finally rerender in the dom

Not sure if this is the right approach. I feel like I must not be the only one trying to achieve this and maybe a better solution exists out there. Anyway I still have no way to load the serialized nodelist JSON into the tag after instanciation ...

Answer (score 0):

One common way to do this is to render the initial list contents within a DOM element id on the initial page request. When the button is clicked ("Load more" in your case), send an XHR request to the backend that will respond with the new, expanded list as an HTML fragment. In the XHR response, replace the HTML of the container DOM element with the new HTML (fragment) content.

This way you are not having to do complicated things like sync JavaScript objects to the DOM. You just replace the DOM contents with the new contents. JavaScript will do this all atomically, so it will appear smooth to the user.

Both the original request, and the subsequent partial request can be rendered by your Liquid tag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I'm aware of this the difficulty here is that my tag is a block and I don't control what's inside. So the diffiuclty is to re-render the tag server side keeping the same "nodelist" ...